# Tableau Filtering Error

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I am attempting to use the JavaScript API to configure a default filter selection state.  Here is the code I am using for this example:

```
$(function() {
  var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
  var url = "https://sometableausite/t/Tableau_Dev/views/MyPath/HomeDashboard?:embed=y&:showShareOptions=true&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no";
  var options = {
     hideTabs: false,
     width: "100%",
     height: "1552px",
     onFirstInteractive: function() {
        var worksheet;


        var filtersVal='';
        var onSuccess = function (filters) {
            console.log("This worksheet has " + filters.length + " filter(s) associated with it.");
            $.each(filters, function (filter, i) {
                // use .value property of each DataValue object
                filtersVal += i.getFieldName() + ", ";
                console.log(filtersVal);
            });
        };

        var onError = function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        };

        viz.getWorkbook().activateSheetAsync("Performance").then(function(sheet) {
            worksheet = sheet;
            worksheet.getWorksheets()[0].getFiltersAsync().then(onSuccess, onError);
        });        
     }
  };

  var viz = new tableau.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);  
});
```

This is just trying to get the available filter options at this point but I am getting a 500 server error and getting kicked into the onError call when calling worksheet.getWorksheets()[0].getFiltersAsync().

Here is the error returned:

POST to https://sometableausite/vizql/t/Tableau_Dev/w/MyPath/v/HomeDashboard/sessions/E49DB48C495E4A858821B95F95AEFB20-0:2/commands/tabsrv/get-filter-info

gives a 500 server error.

TableauException: INTERNAL ERROR

2016-06-22 19:27:53.350
(V2rmuQrmAA0AAEGQy60AAALP,0,2)

What can I do to get the list of filters available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get past the error in the question when trying to query for available filter options.  Instead I found a workaround by simply adding the filters to the URL used.

```
$(function() {
  var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
  var url = "https://sometableausite/t/Tableau_Dev/views/MyPath/HomeDashboard?Business Unit Name=Accounting";
  var options = {
     hideTabs: true,
     width: "100%",
     height: "1552px"
  };

  var viz = new tableau.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);  
});
```